# Output of code prints a weird negative instead of my input

Tags: c++, oop, undefined-behavior

My professor at the end of the class gave us this code and told us to put it in our compiler and play with it to better understand the fundamentals, however, after I copy-pasted the code it doesn't do what it was supposed to do. Here's the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
class Clock {
private:
    int hour;
    int minute;
public:
    Clock();
    Clock(int o, int m);
    Clock(char *text);
    void output();
    void setHour(int h);
    int getHour();
    void setMinute(int m);
    int getMinute();
};
Clock::Clock() {
    hour = 0;
    minute = 0;
}
Clock::Clock(int h, int m) {
    hour = h;
    minute = m;
}
Clock::Clock(char *text) {
    if (strlen(text) == 5) {
        sscanf(text, "%2d%:%2d", &hour, &minute);
    }
    else {
        hour = 0;
        minute = 0;
    }
}
void Clock::output() {
    printf("%02d:%02d\n", hour, minute);
}
void Clock::setHour(int h) {
    if (0 >= h && h < 24) {
        hour = h;
    }
}
int Clock::getHour() {
    return hour;
}
void Clock::setMinute(int m) {
    if (0 >= m && m < 60) {
        minute = m;
    }
}
int Clock::getMinute() {
    return minute;
}
int main() {
    Clock c1;
    c1.output();
    Clock c2(12, 20);
    c2.output();
    Clock c3("16:45");
    c3.output();

}
```

The output of the code should be:

```
00:00
12:20
16:45
```

But instead it is

```
00:00
12:20
16:-858993460
```

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and I've tried the same code on an online compiler (onlinegdb) and the output there is

```
00:00
12:20
16:00
```

The professor uses Dev-C++ or Codeblocks, but didn't run the code, and reaching him for questions at this point is not possible.
What is the problem with the code and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using C library.
my solution is:

```
Clock::Clock(char *text) {
    if (strlen(text) == 5) {
        sscanf(text, "%2d:%2d", &hour, &minute);
    }
    else {
        hour = 0;
        minute = 0;
    }
}
```

In the `main()`, `ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*'` So my solution is:

```
char time[] = "16:45";
Clock c3(time);
c3.output();
```

Comment: Thank you, the issue was simply an extra %,  and thank you for fixing the other warning too!

Comment: @DohnJoe where was the extra % ?